# Google play does not recognize wifi on note tablet

Tags: google-play-store

I have 2012 note tablet. After some software update google play stopped working. It cannot recognize any wifi. (Home or hotspot). Tried resetting to factory settings. No luck. All existing apps work well. Any ideas

Comment: View your date and time settings. They are very important for google account and Play-Store. The time and Date must will correct ...